# Rails Model.find is treating id as array. How do I get this to a act like a regular id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I want to use a method from the Company model for a Product as follows:

```
 def internal_email_recipients
    product = Product.find(params[:id])
    company = Company.find([product.producer.id])
    company.plant_coordinator_emails.reject {|a| a == current_user.contact.email}
  end
```

However, when I do so, I receive an error:

> undefined method `plant_coordinator_emails' for #Array:0x7fd5bc521108

The model associations are:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  
  belongs_to :producer, :class_name => 'Organization'
```

```
class Producer < Organization
  
  has_many :products, :dependent => :destroy, :order => 'products.name'
```

and

```
class Company < Producer
```

which contains the method

```
def plant_coordinator_emails
    plants.map {|plant| plant.coordinator.telcom.email if plant.coordinator}.compact.reject{|p| p == ''}.uniq.join(', ')
  end
```

I would think that it should return all attributes of the Company with the same id as the producer.  There is only one company with this id.

Why is Rails treating this as an array rather than an id?

Comment: You are passing an array of IDs to `Company.find`, so `find` is returning you an array of resulting `Company` objects. Just take out the array brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an array to `company = Company.find([product.producer.id])`
just use `company = Company.find(product.producer.id)` (without the `[]`)

Comment: In the meantime, I had also tried adding ```has_one :company, :class_name => 'Company', :foreign_key => 'id'``` to Producer.rb  and doing ```product.producer.company.plant_coordinator_emails``` - it worked,but your answer seems more organic.

Comment: the `foreign_key` should be `company_id`, or better, remove the option and let rails use the convention, as you are not overriding it. The same with `class_name`, just remove it and define the association as `has_one :company`

Comment: Thank you, Fer.  I had actually tried that and gotten a ```Mysql error```. Funny thing is - there is no separate table referenced by ```company_id```.  Whoever wrote the app set up sub-categories of the ```organizations``` table such as Company, Plant, Certifier. These are determined by the ```type``` column.